# Inline assembly console print

Tags: c, assembly

So, i'm tring to make a simple program to print a string on console, to make this, I have created a simple function with inline assembly, my ideia is, proint a string without use a windows lib or C/C++ functions, like printf or cout.... so, I know the macro assembler compiler of VC++ use the masm sintax... so, I have maded this:

```
void print(char *msg)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov ah, 9
        mov dx, msg
        int 21h
    }
}

int main()
{
    print("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

BUt, i think the use of old DOS interrupts not work fine :(
So, have a way to make this, whiout use printf or cout or c/c++ functions , just C and assembly ???

Comment: Not really. You can't use DOS/BIOS interrupts from within Windows. Then only way to print a string in assembly is to use the Windows API through your architecture's syscall mechanism.

Comment: If you *do* want to try this though, I'd go for something lower level. Try with a full system emulator such as gem5 (if you want to go through the faff of compiling it), or try an x86 simulator such as qemu or Dosbox. You'll need to get a toolchain that will cope with it, but it'll let you mess around straight with assembly without any OS being in the way.